# Fetching and Caching Users in IOS

Tags: swift, caching, realm, chat

I'm building an app that includes real-time group chat where each chat has a "details page" that includes information like group name, time, location (mapview) and a tableview that lists all the participants. The app works like Whatsapp where your "friends" come from your local contacts, so when you login for the first time, all your local friends are saved to Realm. What I'm having a hard time with is how to manage the details page where there is a mix of users stored in Realm and some that need to be fetched (Eg. if you're added to a group with some people you don't know). My current solution loads the Realm users first then loads the others when they are fetched, and this happens each time the view appears. It's very clunky and isn't a very user-friendly experience.

Looking at Whatsapp, when viewing the details page for a group I have not opened before, the page has a slight delay before opening and then displays all the users in unison. After the initial viewing of the details page, any subsequent viewing does not have any delay and all the users are displayed right away (local friends or otherwise).

I'm sure there is some sort of caching involved but I'm not sure what type and where to start. Any input would be great, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project! However, SO is for coding specific issues - write some code and when you get stuck, post it, and we'll take a look. Because of that the question is off topic for SO. Also, the question isn't very clear - *mix of users stored in Realm and some that need to be fetched* - what is 'fetched'? What does *loads the Realm users first then loads the others* what is a Realm user? Does that mean a user that has created an account in Realm via your app? If so, what are 'the others'? When posting, remember only you know your app so clarity is important.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment, it's insightful. I'm not too familiar with SO so I'll take some time today to edit the question and add more context.

Comment: When you have time, see the help guides - they will assist in helping you write excellent questions. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Not that you've done this but it may be helpful and provide future direction as well to take a look at [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)